# How to add a sidebar menu to a flexdashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I want a sidebar panel to show individually  the graphs in a page. So, in the main page there would be 4 graphs all together,  but in the sidebar should appear the title of each graph so you can select it and view individually each one.

Here is a visual representation of what I want: [example](https://si3.bcentral.cl/SetGraficos/#)

Until now I have just created multiple pages and try using {.tabset} to add tabs to each page. It worked but don´t know how to add side pages.